# Why is Choreographer.FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run called even when the app is paused?

Tags: android, lottie

When the app is in the pause state, I am seeing a lot of activity on `Choreographer.FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run`.
Is it normal in some cases for apps? I also see that most of the cases the call, in the end, is `LottieDrawable. onAnimationUpdate` call.

I want to know if this will have any implication on the performance of my app in the pause state, like power usage etc.,[image: This is the screenshot of profiler in pause state]

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Solution moved from question to an answer:</sup>

> It was happening because the Lottie animation in the loop is not paused on pause. Had to pause it when the app is paused.
>
> I was seeing it when a piece of code running in the background. Check if you also have something running in the background.